# Django - Default Profile Picture not showing

Tags: python, django, imagefield

I have a question about images and imagefields. However, the default picture I chose does not show up, only a blank circle. This was my [default picture](https://twibbon.com/content/images/system/default-image.jpg)

Models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    website = models.URLField(default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class ProfilePicture(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', default='profile_image/Default.jpg')
```

Forms.py

```
class UploadPictureForm(forms.Form):
    image = forms.ImageField()
```

profile.html

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="left">
        <div id="profilecard">
             {% if user.userprofile.image %}
                <img class="circular--square" src="{{ }}" width="200" height="200">
            {% endif %}
            <div id="info">
                <br>
                <h3>{{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}</h3>
                <p>@{{ user }}</p>
                <p>{{ user.userprofile.city }}</p>
                <p>{{ user.userprofile.website }}</p>
                <p><i>{{ user.userprofile.description }}</i></p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `src` tag in `profile.html` was not filed. If you want a default image to be used you can put an `else` tag in the template and point the `src` to a static file.

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="left">
        <div id="profilecard">
             {% if user.userprofile.image %}
                <img class="circular--square" src="{{ user.userprofile.image.url }}" width="200" height="200">
            {% endif %}
            <div id="info">
                <br>
                <h3>{{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}</h3>
                <p>@{{ user }}</p>
                <p>{{ user.userprofile.city }}</p>
                <p>{{ user.userprofile.website }}</p>
                <p><i>{{ user.userprofile.description }}</i></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is error in your code that you cannot get image from inside userprofile model so you need to do this:

Change your:

```
{% if user.userprofile.image %}
```

to:

```
{% if user.profilepicture_set.count > 0 %}
```

Change src attrib of img tag to:

```
src="{{ user.profilepicture_set.all.0.image.url }}"
```

Fixed code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="left">
        <div id="profilecard">
             {% if user.profilepicture_set.count > 0 %}
                <img class="circular--square" src="{{ user.profilepicture_set.all.0.image.url }}" width="200" height="200">
            {% endif %}
            <div id="info">
                <br>
                <h3>{{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}</h3>
                <p>@{{ user }}</p>
                <p>{{ user.userprofile.city }}</p>
                <p>{{ user.userprofile.website }}</p>
                <p><i>{{ user.userprofile.description }}</i></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using `related_name` on your `ForeignKey` in `ProfilePicture` class will customize `profilepicture_set` key of user

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='image')
```

You can access it on template like

```
{% if user.image.count > 0 %}
     <img class="circular--square" src="{{ user.image.all.0.image.url }}" width="200" height="200">
{% endif %}
```

Also you can use OneToOneField to ProfilePicture User field if profile picture will be only one:

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

and template:

```
{% if user.profilepicture %}
     <img class="circular--square" src="{{ user.profilepicture.image.url }}" width="200" height="200">
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by using related_name on your Foreign key?

Comment: Updated my answer